# How to compare current system time with an array of times

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using the below code to try and use current system time to tell me the next time in the array.  All it logs out is the last number in the array.  I have searched, and this is how I ended up where I am, but could never get it to work just right.  Thanks

```
self.array = @[@"00:15", @"01:35, "@"05:30", @"06:10", @"07:05", @"07:55", @"08:45", @"09:35", @"10:40", @"11:25", @"12:20", @"13:10", @"14:05", @"15:00", @"15:45", @"16:40", @"17:30", @"18:20", @"19:20", @"20:10", @"21:00", @"22:05", @"22:55"];


NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSDate *formattedCurrentDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:[dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];

for(NSString *stringTime in self.array) {
    NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormat dateFromString:stringTime];
    if([formattedCurrentDate earlierDate:dateFromString]) {
        self.nextTime.text = stringTime;
    }


}
```

Comment: Please update code to show @"01:35", and not @"01:35, "@"05:30"

Quotation error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if your function works fine.
change:

```
for(NSString *stringTime in self.array) {
    NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormat dateFromString:stringTime];
    if([formattedCurrentDate earlierDate:dateFromString]) {
        self.nextTime.text = stringTime;
    }
}
```

to:

```
for(NSString *stringTime in self.array) {
    NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormat dateFromString:stringTime];
    if([formattedCurrentDate compare:dateFromString] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        self.nextTime.text = stringTime;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's actually not correct. `- (NSDate *)earlierDate:(NSDate *)anotherDate` returns the earlier `NSDate` between the two compared. `if([formattedCurrentDate earlierDate:dateFromString])` will only check if the returned pointer is a valid pointer (its not `nil`), which will always be in this case. The correct approach is the one I pointed out in my solution.

Comment: Using a break does not always work as he has the time in order, if the time was not in order your solution would not work.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is behaving exactly as it should, you are having it return an earlier time than the current time, which means every single time is assigned to self.nextTime.text, but you only see the very last assignment, which is the last item in the array.

Further more your **if** statement always returns true if executed correctly, so you will always get true unless you provide an object that is not an NSDate.

Here is the correct way of getting what you would like ***without having to worry about ordering your array.***

```
NSArray *array = @[@"16:40", @"05:30", @"06:10", @"07:05", @"07:55", @"08:45", @"09:35", @"10:40", @"11:25", @"12:20", @"13:10", @"14:05", @"15:00", @"15:45", @"16:40", @"17:30", @"18:20", @"19:20", @"20:10", @"21:00", @"22:05", @"22:55", @"23:55", @"01:35"];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

NSDate *formattedCurrentDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:[dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];

NSDate *laterDate;
NSDate *closestDate;

for(NSString *stringTime in array) {
    NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormat dateFromString:stringTime];
    laterDate = [formattedCurrentDate laterDate:dateFromString];
    if(![laterDate isEqualToDate:formattedCurrentDate]){
        closestDate = [laterDate earlierDate:closestDate];
    }
}
NSLog(@"Closest Date: %@", [dateFormat stringFromDate:closestDate] );
```

Comment: That's not correct either. Your piece of code it seems to getting the earlier date of all inside the array, which in this case will always be the first one `@"00:15"` . Besides it, you first told in the fisrt paragrap that the code is behaving exactly as it should, and the in the second paragraph you told that will always return true. How's that??

Comment: 1. The code is behaving like it should, but it's not the result he wants. 2. Lucas, the earliest date depending on what time your run it will always be 00:15 (the earliest date in the array) unless you run the application between 00:01-00:14 of which the system date will be younger.

Comment: Your second point is true, the `earliestDate` pointer will always hold 00:15 unless the current date is between  00:01-00:14, and due the fact that's clearly NOT what the user wants in his question , this is wrong. See "I am using the below code to try and use current system time to tell me the next time in the array.(...)" . Besides that, you still have a inconsistency in your text. Negative my anwser will not make this any more correct.

Comment: Ahh, now that I see what he is asking I have updated. Also does not require order to be a factor.

Comment: Nop, sorry but that's wrong again. Just change the first element of the array by any with a later time than the current date. So, the line `earliestDate = [formattedCurrentDate earlierDate:dateFromString];` will get the `formattedCurrentDate` and the loop will break, even though there's is some earlier desired time afterwards.

Comment: @BenCoffman ur sol is not generic.As Lucas mentioned u r code completely depend upon the array input.If you change the array it is giving wrong result.

Comment: Updated to a cleaner solution that works and is easy to understand.

Comment: @BenCoffman executed ur code.But closed date is showing current time.But according to question it should print next time.

Comment: Nop, sorry but not again again. Your code seems to be returning always the current date. Just try with this array:
`NSArray *array = @[@"02:25", @"01:35", @"05:30", @"06:10", @"07:05", @"07:55", @"08:45", @"09:35", @"10:40", @"11:25", @"12:20", @"13:10", @"14:05", @"15:00", @"15:45", @"16:40", @"17:30", @"18:20", @"19:20", @"20:10", @"21:00", @"22:05", *PLACE HERE STRING WITH ACTUAL HOUR PLUS 2 MINUTES*, @"22:55", @"23:55"];`

Comment: @BenCoffman seems not possible.I have just copied ur codebase.And Each time I run I am getting current time instead of next.

Comment: @iPhoneDev there is literally no way you could be seeing that unless the current time is later than every item in the array. In which case a decision would have to be made on what would be considered "next time" since the day of the year is not taken into consideration.

Comment: @BenCoffman Tell me one thing.I am in IST(GMT+5:30).My cur time is 11:03 while running it is showing 11:03 instead of 11:25.May be according to u r time zone u have all later item.Please change u r time zone and test.

Comment: @iPhoneDev Ok I did what you said and I DID get your error. I updated hopefully for the last time. :)

Comment: @BenCoffman Sorry.Again the code is depend upon the array input.If you change the array it is not working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34960/discussion-between-ben-coffman-and-iphonedev)

Comment: Hi, now your code seems to be working as expected, and I edited my answer to remove to remove where I was telling the it's not working. Although, there's a minor typo in `[NSDate alloc] init];` where actually you don't even need to allocate a memory position for `closestDate` , since it's just a pointer to hold one of the allocated `dateFromString`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more generic solution, that doesn't depend on the order of the array, you could use the code below:

```
NSArray *array = @[@"02:25", @"01:35", @"05:30", @"06:10", @"07:05", @"07:55", @"08:45", @"09:35", @"10:40", @"11:25", @"12:20", @"13:10", @"14:05", @"15:00", @"15:45", @"16:40", @"17:30", @"18:20", @"19:20", @"20:10", @"21:00", @"22:05", @"22:55", @"23:55"];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

NSDate *formattedCurrentDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:[dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
NSTimeInterval currentInterval = [formattedCurrentDate timeIntervalSince1970];
NSTimeInterval smallerInterval = CGFLOAT_MAX;

for(NSString *stringTime in array) {
    NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormat dateFromString:stringTime];
    NSTimeInterval dateFromStringInterval = [dateFromString timeIntervalSince1970];

    NSTimeInterval actualInterval = (dateFromStringInterval - currentInterval);

    if(actualInterval > 0 && actualInterval < smallerInterval){
        smallerInterval = actualInterval;
        self.nextTime.text = stringTime;
    }
}
```

This code is getting the closest next hour of the current hour, independent of it's index inside the array. And doesn't require more allocations or any sorting of arrays, like @Sandeep solutions (that do works).

Explaining:
The actualInterval is getting the difference in seconds between all dates and the current date. This variable (which is a double, actually) will only be positive to future hours (past hours will be negative).

So, all the code is doing is getting the smaller difference between future hours. This is, I think, the best solution to this case.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  That works better, but it is printing off everything after the current time.  So current time is 20:05, it prints off the next three to console, and then the UILabel get the last one in the array.  How do you only get the next one??  Thanks for the help

Comment: The NSLog is just a test, I let the rest to you. So, what do you really want? Just the first next time after the current time in the array?

Comment: Just the next time in the array.  So in the case current is 20:25, the next time in the array is 21:00.  That is what I am trying to get.  Thanks, sorry if it seems like a cheesy question.

Comment: Just edited. Now your self.nextTime property will hold your desired hour.

Comment: It's important to notice that for this solution works everytime, always make sure to get the hours inside your `self.array` ordered, like it already are, otherwise it won't work as expected.

Comment: Shouldn't have to order array, see my answer for a solution where order doesn't matter.

Comment: Like I said, your solution is still wrong. I'm editing with a real solution that the order doesn't matter

Comment: My solution is all good now, thanks for keeping my code in check.

Comment: Not this time again, dude, sorry. If you correct, I remove the "wrong" reference from my answer!.

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSArray  *array = @[@"23:15", @"01:35", @"05:30", @"06:10", @"07:05", @"07:55", @"08:45", @"09:35", @"10:40", @"11:25", @"12:20", @"13:10", @"14:05", @"15:00", @"15:45", @"16:40", @"17:30", @"18:20", @"19:20", @"20:10", @"21:00", @"22:05", @"22:55", @"23:55"];

    NSMutableArray *datesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

    //Convert all strings to dates
    for (NSString *str in array)
    {

        NSDate *formattedCurrentDate = [dateFormat dateFromString: str];

        [datesArray addObject:formattedCurrentDate];
    }

    //Sort dates.
    NSArray *sortedArray = [datesArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

    NSString *date = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDate *formattedTodatDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:date];

    //Print the desired date
    for(NSDate *stringTime in sortedArray)
    {
        if([formattedTodatDate compare:stringTime] == NSOrderedAscending)
        {
            NSLog(@"Result is %@", [dateFormat stringFromDate:stringTime]);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Try the above code. I just followed what others have mentioned with sorting dates.